# How to use LiteSpeed server with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, litespeed

On my search i've got only info about replacement of Apache with LiteSpeed. My question is rather: how to use them together?

I think about a similar setup, where Apache is used together with Nginx, where Nginx plays a reverse proxy role.

Is such setup possible? Does somebody know a use case or documentation about it?

Comment: Like @NStorm said that you don't really need to make both LSWS and Apache together. But you can still do it if you want, LSWS as a reverse proxy, https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:proxy:start

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need something you don't know a use case for?

LiteSpeed are designed as a drop-in replacement for Apache. Nginx doesn't directly supports all things that Apache can, .htaccess files for example. That is why it is used sometimes in conjunction with Apache.

But LiteSpeed supports them and can simply replace Apache. It was designed this way. So it's mostly useless to set up it with Apache.